# Need Canvas courses user-info course-info

Tags: canvas-lms

I'm new with Canvas lms and just wondering if anyone know how to get the user info and course id. need some examples

Below is the link I found, but still can't figure out how to use this in my php to grab the user info. 
https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.object_ids.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the OAuth2 ACCESS-TOKEN and your USER-ID, you can simply use HTTP GET requests to obtain this information.

In order to get your user info, you need to perform a GET request to the following URL: 
`https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/users/<USER-ID>/profile?access_token=<ACCESS-TOKEN>`

In order to get course id for the list of courses you belong to, you need to perform a GET request to the following URL: `https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses?access_token=<ACCESS-TOKEN>`

For more capabilities you can use the following API documentation:
https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/index.html